# Elasticsearch and Rails: Using ngram to search for part of a word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, elasticsearch, rails-activerecord

I am trying to use the Elasticsearch-Gem in my project. As I understand: By now there is no need for the Tire-Gem anymore, or am I wrong?

In my project I have a search (obivously), which currently applies to one model. Now I am trying to avoid wildcards, since they don't scale well, but I can't seem to get the ngram-Analyzers work properly. If I search for whole words, the search still works, but not for parts of it.

```
class Pictures < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  settings  :analysis => {
          :analyzer => {
            :my_index_analyzer => {
                :tokenizer => "keyword",
                :filter => ["lowercase", "substring"]
            },
            :my_search_analyzer => {
              :tokenizer => "keyword",
              :filter => ["lowercase", "substring"]
            }
          },
          :filter => {
            :substring => {
              :type => "nGram",
              :min_gram => 2,
              :max_gram => 50
            }
          }
    } do  
mapping do
  indexes :title, 
  :properties => {
    :type => "string",
    :index_analyzer => 'my_index_analyzer',
    :search_analyzer => "my_search_analyzer"
  }
```

Maybe somebody can give me a hint into the right direction.

Comment: Always worth checking that your settings and mappings are what you expect by querying elasticsearch: `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/pictures/_settings?pretty=true'` and `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/pictures/_mapping?pretty=true`

Comment: Did you get it resolved? I too am stuck at this. I am able to get it working through CURL, but not using Elasticsearch-Rails.

Comment: Would love to know if somebody figured this out. Documentation is very bad -- I don't understand why they use this `mapping do ...` syntax instead of just giving a hash like you would pass to ES?

Answer (score 1):

I have given up on defining schema in the model class. In fact, it does not make much sense too.

So here is what I have done. A schema/mapping definition the db/ folder and a rake task to build it.

https://gist.github.com/geordee/9313f4867d61ce340a08

In the model

```
def as_indexed_json(options={})
  self.as_json(only: [:id, :name, :description, :price])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an index for suggestions based on edgeNGram (like nGram, but always starting at the left side of the word) with this settings:

```
{
   "en_suggestions": {
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "analysis": {
               "filter": {
                  "tpNGramFilter": {
                     "min_gram": "4",
                     "type": "edgeNGram",
                     "max_gram": "50"
                  }
               },
               "analyzer": {
                  "tpNGramAnalyzer": {
                     "type": "custom",
                     "filter": [
                        "tpNGramFilter"
                     ],
                     "tokenizer": "lowercase"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and this mapping:

```
{
   "en_suggestions": {
      "mappings": {
         "suggest": {
            "properties": {
               "proposal": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "tpNGramAnalyzer"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Where are you setting up those configurations? Are they configured in your rails Class or are you importing those settings from somewhere?

Comment: I'm not using Rails, but Java... But in the end you should be able to sent some json to ES no matter from what language to archive the results.

The code I posted in my answer comes from reading out the mapping:
GET /en_suggestions/_mapping?pretty=true
and the settings:
GET /en_suggestions/_settings?pretty=true

I'm using "Sense" for Google Chrome to issue this commands and also to experiment before molding it into programming code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into that as well as into "Sense"